# Can't install CocoaPods on OS X Mavericks Xcode 5.1

Tags: ruby, xcode, macos, rubygems, cocoapods

I tried to install CocoaPods on 3 of my Macs and I'm getting the same error. Does anyone knows how to fix that?

I'm running OS X Mavericks 10.9.2 and Xcode 5.1. ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674)

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/Menicucci/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby -rubygems /Users/Menicucci/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-0.9.6/bin/rake RUBYARCHDIR=/Users/Menicucci/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.0.0/xcodeproj-0.14.1 RUBYLIBDIR=/Users/Menicucci/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.0.0/xcodeproj-0.14.1
/Users/Menicucci/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- /Users/Menicucci/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-0.9.6/bin/rake (LoadError)

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Menicucci/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.14.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Menicucci/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.0.0/xcodeproj-0.14.1/gem_make.out
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply\_definedsuppress'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cocoapods with Xcode 6 and 10.10 Yosemite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018355/cocoapods-with-xcode-6-and-10-10-yosemite)

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to Xcode 5.1 - its already reported as a bug to Ruby.

https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9624#change-45736

There is some more additional discussion here:
[Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)