# Rails 4 bundle update error with gem atomic 1.1.16

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bundle, atomic

Rails bundle update keeps failing on processing atomic gem v 1.1.16. Have searched the web back and forth for solution. Checked gcc --version:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-   dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Installed xcode command lines, ran gem system updates, uninstalled previous atomic versions and tried to reinstall 1.1.16. Same result:

```
...
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [atomic_reference.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

Does anybody have a hint? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

These are the nearest to solution I have found so far from [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/frank-discuss/JpKbJIJVb7Q) and [github](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/issues/96#issuecomment-35016502).

Seems to be a yet unsolved issue of osx Mavericks and/or Xcode.
But the modified bundle install hint at least gets it to run complete.

Comment: malvolio, this same question has just been asked again - you might get a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670712/an-error-occurred-while-installing-atomic-1-1-16-and-bundler-cannot-continue

Comment: Thanks. I solved the issue by reinstalling everything from rvm to the rails framework.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply\_definedsuppress'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it's a problem with the version of Rails and Ruby you are using.

I'm using Rails 4.0.2 and RVM 1.25.16 for management of ruby versions (currently have 2.0.0p247 and 2.0.0-p353). I'm on OS X Mavericks, Version 10.9.1.

I originally installed ruby 2.0.0p247, and this is still the default for terminal. But I later installed with RVM ruby 2.0.0p353. I was also getting errors with install of the atomic gem, even for a new project. But when I switch to the latest version of ruby with rvm (rvm ruby-2.0.0-p353), everything now installs properly. I'm not sure what's going on or why that fixed it. I hope this helps.