# An error occurred while installing atomic (1.1.16) and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm trying to create a new rails app but while bundling this error raises...

it's the first time i face this error !!

```
Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/atomic-1.1.16 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/atomic-1.1.16/ext/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing atomic (1.1.16), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install atomic -v '1.1.16'` succeeds before bundling.
```

My rails version is Rails 4.0.1

My os is mac 10.9 mavericks

Comment: What's in the file `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/atomic-1.1.16/ext/gem_make.out`?

Comment: Are you getting this error in your results: ```clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]``` Because I have the same issue as you with Mavericks >:(

Answer (score 4):

Try this solution from [here](http://bruteforce.gr/bypassing-clang-error-unknown-argument.html):

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install atomic -v '1.1.16'
```

or if you want to export it:

```
export ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future
gem install atomic -v '1.1.16'
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything unfortunately :(

Comment: @lartis93 Is xcode installed? It worked for me, but I didn't have xcode installed and I wasn't using RVM. Maybe it's because I was using the system ruby. Maybe try ```rvm use system``` first.

Answer (score 0):

try installing development tools

http://www.computersnyou.com/2025/2013/06/install-command-line-tools-in-osx-10-9-mavericks-how-to/