# error compiling atomic gem in mac os x after xcode update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, atomic

I am having issues with the ruby gem atomic after upgrading to xcode 5.1 2 days ago

this is the error that I get:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for libkern/OSAtomic.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling atomic_reference.c
atomic_reference.c:57:59: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'void **' to   parameter of type 'volatile int64_t *' (aka 'volatile long long *') [-Wincompatible-    pointer-types]
    if (OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64(expect_value, new_value, &DATA_PTR(self))) {
                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/libkern/OSAtomic.h:507:93: note: passing argument to parameter '__theValue' here
bool    OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64( int64_t __oldValue, int64_t __newValue, volatile int64_t *__theValue );
                                                                                          ^
1 warning generated.
linking shared-object atomic_reference.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-  argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the  future
make: *** [atomic_reference.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.16 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.16/ext/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing atomic (1.1.16), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install atomic -v '1.1.16'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Is read that it had something to do with the gcc version that came with the new xcode version, is this possible? do I need to downgrade or is there some other way to solve it?
Or is the reason for this error not xcode?

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply\_definedsuppress'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by downgrading to the Xcode version 5.0.2