# Trouble installing rails on MAC OS X 10.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Having trouble installing rails on mac and wondering if someone could help me:

```
dannys-mbp-2:~ Danny1$ sudo gem install rails
```

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for libkern/OSAtomic.h... yes
creating Makefile
```

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make

```
"DESTDIR="
compiling atomic_reference.c
atomic_reference.c:57:59: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'void **' to parameter of type 'volatile int64_t *' (aka 'volatile long long *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    if (OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64(expect_value, new_value, &DATA_PTR(self))) {
                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/libkern/OSAtomic.h:507:93: note: passing argument to parameter '__theValue' here
bool    OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64( int64_t __oldValue, int64_t __newValue, volatile int64_t *__theValue );
                                                                                        ^
1 warning generated.
linking shared-object atomic_reference.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [atomic_reference.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.16 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/atomic-1.1.16/gem_make.out
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply\_definedsuppress'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)

Answer (score 3):

I was dealing with this and finally stumbled upon the Bug report for this.  I used the following command and it worked for me:

`sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install rails`

Official report: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9624

Comment: It pushed through but had some commands "skipping" such as: unable to convert "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/akshaysurve.jpg, skipping

Comment: This seems to be problems with the "font or character libraries" but not sure how that will impact my future coding.