# Cannot install pushmeup plugin

Tags: ruby, cordova, rubygems, push-notification, phonegap-plugins

I try to install **pushmeup** plugin for phonegap push notifications (ios).
When I run command **sudo gem install pushmeup** I get this error:

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing pushmeup:  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
> ```
>
> extconf.rb creating Makefile
>
> make "DESTDIR=" clean
>
> make "DESTDIR=" compiling generator.c linking shared-object
>   json/ext/generator.bundle clang: error: unknown argument:
>   '-multiply_definedsuppress'
>   [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future] clang: note:
>   this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the
>   future make: *** [generator.bundle] Error 1
>
> make failed, exit code 2
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection. Results
>   logged to
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/json-1.8.1/gem_make.out

**GitHub:**

> https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

**Params:**

> **ruby -v** ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674)
>   [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
>
> **gem -v**
>   2.2.2
>
> **Mac OS X** v 10.9.2
>
> **XCode** Version 5.1 (5B130a)
>
> **cordova -v**
>   3.4.0-0.1.3

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply\_definedsuppress'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Apple broke something on Mavericks, they removed the warning flag `unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future` acording to this issue: [#528](https://github.com/boxen/our-boxen/issues/528)

Please try this command:

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future sudo gem install pushmeup
```

what it does? this sets the environment variable: `ARCHFLAGS=` this adds a ignore warnings `-Wno-error=` and this is the warning that you don't see in mavericks `unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future` (which should be ignored)

In [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> Compiler
>
> As of Apple LLVM compiler version 5.1 (clang-502) and later, the
>   optimization level -O4 no longer implies link time optimization (LTO).
>   In order to build with LTO explicitly use the -flto option in addition
>   to the optimization level flag. (15633276) The Apple LLVM compiler in
>   Xcode 5.1 treats unrecognized command-line options as errors. This
>   issue has been seen when building both Python native extensions and
>   Ruby Gems, where some invalid compiler options are currently
>   specified. Projects using invalid compiler options will need to be
>   changed to remove those options. To help ease that transition, the
>   compiler will temporarily accept an option to downgrade the error to a
>   warning:
>
> -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future
>
> Note: This option will not be supported in the future. To workaround
>   this issue, set the ARCHFLAGS environment variable to downgrade the
>   error to a warning. For example, you can install a Python native
>   extension with:
>
> $ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future
>   easy_install ExtensionName
>
> Similarly, you can install a Ruby Gem with:
>
> $ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future
>   gem install GemName 16214764 updated

**EDIT HISTORY**

just tested on my machine, using same ruby:

```
$ gem install pushmeup
Fetching: pushmeup-0.1.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed pushmeup-0.1.2
Parsing documentation for pushmeup-0.1.2
Installing ri documentation for pushmeup-0.1.2
Done installing documentation for pushmeup after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
```

From what i saw you are not using `rvm` or `rbenv` so the problem is not in `gcc` dependencies

Accordingly to the output provided, the error was when installing `json-1.8.1`.
Can you post the log located at: `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/json-1.8.1/gem_make.out` ?

Comment: sh-3.2# cat /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [generator.bundle] Error 1