# Error installing RedCloth (4.2.9) on OS X 10.9.2

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll

I try to install Jekyll with pages, using [enter link description here](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages).
The process stops when installing RedCloth (4.2.9): "Make sure that `gem install RedCloth -v '4.2.9'` succeeds before bundling."

The results below (I changed https in H due to url limitations in this Question).
I run OS X 10.9.2

Step 1 = OK

```
mikea:mego mikea$ ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
```

Step 2 = OK

```
mikea:mego mikea$ sudo gem install bundler
Password:
Successfully installed bundler-1.5.3
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.5.3
1 gem installed
```

Step 3 = NOK

```
mikea:mego mikea$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from H://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching additional metadata from h://rubygems.org/..

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-cflags=-w
checking for main() in -lc... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling redcloth_attributes.c
compiling redcloth_inline.c
compiling redcloth_scan.c
linking shared-object redcloth_scan.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [redcloth_scan.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/mikea/.bundler/tmp/25125/gems/RedCloth-4.2.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/mikea/.bundler/tmp/25125/gems/RedCloth-4.2.9/ext/redcloth_scan/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing RedCloth (4.2.9), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install RedCloth -v '4.2.9'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply\_definedsuppress'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by install rbenv with brew, and then install ruby 2.1.1 through rbenv. Finally change the ruby version to 2.1.1. Here is the command:

```
$brew update
$brew install rbenv
$rbenv install 2.1.1
$rbenv global 2.1.1
```

log out. Now you can try your 3 step.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I will try later. Now I can run Jekyll after starting the following command:
jekyll serve --watch --baseurl ""

Comment: Before I could use rbenv install, I also had to ```brew install ruby-build```

Comment: THX to @sandover for that info :)

Comment: .. or actually I ran into further problems. You can just run `rvm install ruby-2.1.1` then ruby gets updated to 2.1.1

Comment: this post is old. should do this instead for the last 2 rbenv install 3.1.2
rbenv global 3.1.2 as noted here https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/wiki#you-dont-have-write-permissions-for-the-libraryrubygems260-directory

Answer (score 0):

I did not use hue answer to install rbenv with brew. Maybe you can use it.
I solved the problem by using Terminal, first go to the folder in Sites and then type:

```
jekyll serve --watch --baseurl ""
```