# Cannot run bundle install due to failure in installing atomic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, atomic

The entire content on terminal is the following:

```
Your Gemfile lists the gem rake (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
Your Gemfile lists the gem rspec (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching additional metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies..................
Using rake (10.2.1)
Using i18n (0.6.9)
Using minitest (4.7.5)
Using multi_json (1.9.2)

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for libkern/OSAtomic.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling atomic_reference.c
atomic_reference.c:57:59: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'void **' to parameter of type 'volatile int64_t *' (aka 'volatile long long *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    if (OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64(expect_value, new_value, &DATA_PTR(self))) {
                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/libkern/OSAtomic.h:507:93: note: passing argument to parameter '__theValue' here
bool    OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64( int64_t __oldValue, int64_t __newValue, volatile int64_t *__theValue );
                                                                                            ^
1 warning generated.
linking shared-object atomic_reference.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [atomic_reference.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/my_name/.bundler/tmp/1029/gems/atomic-1.1.16 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/my_name/.bundler/tmp/1029/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/atomic-1.1.16/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing atomic (1.1.16), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install atomic -v '1.1.16'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: write your gem file here..

Comment: Problem solved. 
One of my friend says it's a bug and suggests me to update ruby and run bundle install again. I did what he said and everything goes alright.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply\_definedsuppress'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)