# Install Calabash-Android causes error on OS X Mavericks

Tags: android, ruby, cucumber, osx-mavericks, calabash

I need some help with trying to install Calabash-Android. After installing rvm, home-brew, when I install Calabash i get a strange error:

```
sudo gem install calabash-android
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing calabash-android:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lc... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling gherkin_lexer_ar.c
ragel/i18n/ar.c.rl:440:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-    Wreturn-type]
}
^
ext/gherkin_lexer_ar/gherkin_lexer_ar.c:864:18: warning: unused variable     'lexer_en_main' [-Wunused-const-variable]
static const int lexer_en_main = 1;
             ^
2 warnings generated.
linking shared-object gherkin_lexer_ar.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-    argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [gherkin_lexer_ar.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/gherkin-2.12.2 for   inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/gherkin-        2.12.2/ext/gherkin_lexer_ar/gem_make.out
doronkatz@Dorons-MacBook-Air ~ $ mkdir ~/android
doronkatz@Dorons-MacBook-Air ~ $ mkdir ~/android
mkdir: /Users/doronkatz/android: File exists
```

doronkatz@Dorons-MacBook-Air ~ $ sudo gem install calabash-android
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing calabash-android:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

checking for main() in -lc... yes
creating Makefile

```
make "DESTDIR="
```

compiling gherkin_lexer_ar.c
ragel/i18n/ar.c.rl:440:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
ext/gherkin_lexer_ar/gherkin_lexer_ar.c:864:18: warning: unused variable 'lexer_en_main' [-Wunused-const-variable]
static const int lexer_en_main = 1;
^
2 warnings generated.
linking shared-object gherkin_lexer_ar.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-  argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [gherkin_lexer_ar.bundle] Error 1

```
 Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/gherkin-2.12.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/gherkin-   2.12.2/ext/gherkin_lexer_ar/gem_make.out
```

Not sure what the error means, I have installed Xcode tools for mavericks as well. Any thoughts out there?

Comment: I downgraded to 1.8 of ruby and it worked. Interesting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply\_definedsuppress'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and I just found out a solution for this.

I found one related problem here:

http://techespanto.wordpress.com/2013/03/29/upgrade-ruby-version-on-mac-osx/

and it suggested I had to upgrade the ruby version on my machine. The first two commands in that link are not working, so I leave you here what I did:

Install the command line tools for mac with:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Install homebrew in your mac with:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

Install rvm with:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails --autolibs=enable
```

List the latest ruby versions with:

```
rvm list known
```

Install the latest ruby version with:

```
rvm install ruby-<version>
```

(for me it was `ruby-2.1-head`)

And that's all. Hope it works for you as well!

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/22787223/1165581

---

I looked at the calabash-ios google group for you and I think I have the solution for your

Try installing it like this

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install calabash-cucumber
```

If that fails you can try to downgrade xcode from 5.1 to one of the previous(Preferences->Locations).

And the reference link

---