# Install Calabash-cucumber error on OS X Mavericks

Tags: ios, ruby, cucumber, osx-mavericks, calabash

I am trying to install calabash on OS-x mavericks for automation by refering to the link: (https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios)

I have installed latest version of ruby, homebrew, rbenv.

Please note that command

```
homebrew doctor
```

is giving me one warning only:

```
Warning: Xcode is installed to a directory with a space in the name.
This will cause some formulae to fail to build.
```

I was not able to remove this warning. Also some forum suggested that this may be harmless.

after struggling with installation issue for 2 days straight now,
I am stuck at this point where I am getting the following error:

```
nitzs-iMac:tabbedapp nitzarg$ sudo gem install calabash-cucumber
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing calabash-cucumber:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lc... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling gherkin_lexer_ar.c
ragel/i18n/ar.c.rl:440:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-            type]
}
^
ext/gherkin_lexer_ar/gherkin_lexer_ar.c:864:18: warning: unused variable 'lexer_en_main'         [-Wunused-const-variable]
static const int lexer_en_main = 1;
             ^
2 warnings generated.
linking shared-object gherkin_lexer_ar.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [gherkin_lexer_ar.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/gherkin-2.12.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/gherkin-   2.12.2/ext/gherkin_lexer_ar/gem_make.out
```

I am assuming the installation has failed because the terminal fails to recognise calabash command. 
I need to know why I am getting the error? Its it a mavericks issue? Or is it a Xcode-5 issue?

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that I have also installed the "latest" xcode command line tools.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply\_definedsuppress'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the calabash-ios google group for you and I think I have the solution for your

Try installing it like this

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install calabash-cucumber
```

If that fails you can try to downgrade xcode from 5.1 to one of the previous(Preferences->Locations).

And the reference [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/calabash-ios/ERROR%243A%2420Failed%2420to%2420build%2420gem%2420native%2420extension/calabash-ios/UNWY__xgJts/h9JFDPhIYwUJ)

Comment: Hi @Lasse , I saw the same query on google groups. the commang should be -->" sudo export ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future bundle install; sudo gem install calabash-cucumber ". But its giving me the same error. Downgrading seems to be far fetched option right now as app im testing is for xcode 5. Can you support it(downgrade) with any specific argument?

Comment: Not that I know of unfortunately. But I can see that you raised your question in the google group, and there I am sure you will get an answer soon.

Comment: There is another post on this here at Stackoverflow as well, it has an alternative answer which has just been accepted. So you can try that if you have not already. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22765773/1165581)