# undefined local variable or method `start_test_server_in_background' for main:Object

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, calabash

I try develop automatic test on Android device.
I use Calabash and Ruby on Rails, version 2.1.2

I execute command:

```
calabash-android console aplikacja.apk -p tablet
```

After this I execute command in console:

```
/home/maciek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:222: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/maciek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2 in PATH, mode 040777
/home/maciek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:222: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/maciek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2 in PATH, mode 040777
2.1.2 :001 >start_test_server_in_background
```

After this I get error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `start_test_server_in_background' for main:Object
    from (irb):1
    from /home/maciek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

I use real device - Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7" with Android 4.1.1

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**First thing to try** — execute `unset IRBRC` in console and only after launch Calabash.

**Second one** is to use Ruby version below 2.0 — e.g. 1.9.3.

> There are several issues when running  with Ruby 2.0. Few proofs:
>
> - https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/issues/342
> - [Install Calabash-Android causes error on OS X Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22723980/install-calabash-android-causes-error-on-os-x-mavericks)
>
> I've seen the same behavior myself, version downgrade/upgrade helps. But it looks like it relates to calabash-android only.

Comment: Why would the ruby version matter?

Comment: There are several issues related to the usage of Ruby 2.0 with calabash. I can find several links proving that if you'd like.

Comment: Please do provide the links.  I haven't seen any problems related to ruby 2.* and calabash-ios.  I do periodic regression tests on the supported ruby versions.  We have had some suspicious behavior with rvm users though.  This is the first I have heard about a systemic problem with ruby 2.*.  The calabash-ios/android team primarily uses rbenv.

Comment: I have a question. Have you tried to execute 'unset IRBRC' in console and then launch calabash?

Answer (score 1):

This is because rvm set IRBRC variable to ruby console . it works if you unset the IRBRC value before opening calabash-console

Please do the following steps :

$unset IRBRC

$calabash-android console aplikacja.apk -p tablet

$start_test_server_in_background

post your comment below

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is this:

https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/pull/383

I think you can do this to work around this problem.

`$ IRBRC=  calabash-android console aplikacja.apk -p tablet`