# undefined local variable or method `start_test_server_in_background' for #<Object:0x007ffc49a5e130>

Tags: testing, cucumber, calabash, calabash-ios

This has been asked before for .12.0 but I am now getting a similar error in .14.2 .

Up until a few weeks ago I was running calabash.framework 11.4 because it worked, was stable, and it was under lock and key on our development server. We went through a recent state of updating all of our gems and services and while our build server still functions calabash is no longer recognizing the "start_server_in_background" method.  I am at a loss on how to remedy this.  I tried a complete wipe and reinstall on my local mirror to no avail, and am considering rolling everything back to the previous working versions. However I would like to solve this to keep everything up to date.

I have tried the following solutions with no success.

[undefined local variable or method `start_test_server_in_background' for main:Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250022/undefined-local-variable-or-method-start-test-server-in-background-for-mainob)

https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/issues/669

https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/issues/371

This is my error after the scenario runs

```
undefined local variable or method `start_test_server_in_background' for #<Object:0x007f9a7c07ba48> (NameError)
      /Users/mycomp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/rspec-expectations-3.2.1/lib/rspec/matchers.rb:926:in `method_missing'
      /Users/mycomp/KonyiOSWorkspace/user/Kony/iOS-6.0.3.GA_v201503250510/VMAppWithKonylib/features/mobile/helpers/ios/support/app_life_cycle_hooks.rb:44:in `Before'
```

Comment: You'll have to show us your Cucumber launch hooks and env files.  Can you create a gist with the contents of features/support/.  RE: rolling back.  I would strongly advise that you always run with the most recent version of Calabash iOS and Android.  We are pushing fixes all the time, especially on the iOS side - Xcode and iOS are moving targets.

Comment: gist you requested with env.rb, json_expander, and lanch hook.  https://gist.github.com/CoreyBBVAMesser/df534b439222a1bfddae

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommend way of launching the application is to use:

```
options = { }
launcher.relaunch(options)
launcher.calabash_notify(self)
```

In your support/env.rb file you need to:

```
require 'calabash-cucumber/cucumber'
```

not `calabash-cucumber`.