# sudo gem install jekyll -- failure -- clang error unknown argument

Tags: ruby, rubygems, clang

Jekyll won't install via `gem install` below is the error. Even further below is some versions of things and locations.

```
sudo gem install jekyll                                                                                                                                    
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling porter.c
porter.c:359:27: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
  if (a > 1 || a == 1 && !cvc(z, z->k - 1)) z->k--;
            ~~ ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
porter.c:359:27: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this warning
  if (a > 1 || a == 1 && !cvc(z, z->k - 1)) z->k--;
                      ^
               (                          )
1 warning generated.
compiling porter_wrap.c
linking shared-object stemmer.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [stemmer.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2 for  inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/fast-stemmer-1.0.2/gem_make.out
```

Direct outputs from terminal of commands:

```
[~]$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

[~]$ ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]

[~]$ which gem 
/usr/bin/gem
[~]$ gem --version
2.2.2

[~]$ which clang
/usr/bin/clang

[~]$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

OSX 10.9.2, Xcode version 5.1

Comment: is this similar question helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same issue encountered in [Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)

I found the comments in this issue for the jekyll repo helpful:
https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/2125

If you're using rvm or rbenv you can checkout Ruby 2.1.1 and it should install smoothly.

Otherwise you can install with 
`ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install jekyll`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect This worked, its also worth noting that this works with `ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]` for me at least.