# Clang build error when trying to install Jekyll

Tags: rubygems, clang, jekyll, redcloth

I am trying to install Jekyll using the instruction on this page (https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages). However, at the second step, `bundle install`, the following is output

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for main() in -lc... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling redcloth_attributes.c
compiling redcloth_inline.c
compiling redcloth_scan.c
linking shared-object redcloth_scan.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [redcloth_scan.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /var/folders/39/fxww36m16ddggmf4plpl3mv40000gn/T/bundler20140403-1735-6tlte3/RedCloth-4.2.9/gems/RedCloth-4.2.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/folders/39/fxww36m16ddggmf4plpl3mv40000gn/T/bundler20140403-1735-6tlte3/RedCloth-4.2.9/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/RedCloth-4.2.9/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing RedCloth (4.2.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install RedCloth -v '4.2.9'` succeeds before bundling.
```

`clang --version` outputs

```
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

on my machine, and Ruby is version `2.0.0p247`.

I've seen a number of other people's questions about this, but none of them have the same issue, nor do the solutions suggested to them seem particularly relevant, apart from the idea of somehow getting bundler to use `GCC` instead of `Clang`, which I don't know how to accomplish. One idea I have is to get `Clang` to treat this as a warning instead of an error, as the message implies is possible in this version, but I don't know how I would do that either, especially in the context of a terminal command like `bundle install`. How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply\_definedsuppress'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)

Comment: @Nakilon While I agree that this is sort of a duplicate in that you can answer my question with that question fairly easily, I think this question does have merit on its own for the simple reason that it fixes a problem with the canonical tutorial for setting up a Jekyll based blog on Github. I couldn't find that question by Googling this problem either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used `ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future bundle install`
 to treat the error as a warning.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install jekyll
```