# Rails issue new project mac osx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is pure silly of a setup on mac osx. I am trying to follow the guide get started on ruby on rails website, but can't. Every time I try the following command I get an error. All shown below...please advise on what to do. This is becoming ridiculous

```
$ rails new blog
      create  
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/mailers/.keep
      create  app/models/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/bundle
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
         run  bundle install


Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system Rubygems.
You can cancel this installation and run:

    bundle install --path vendor/bundle

to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your password
and install the bundled gems to Rubygems using sudo.

Password: 
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.2.2
Using i18n 0.6.9
Using minitest 4.7.5
Using multi_json 1.9.2
Installing thread_safe 0.3.2
Using tzinfo 0.3.39
Using activesupport 4.0.4
Using builder 3.1.4
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using rack 1.5.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using actionpack 4.0.4
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.4
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 4.0.4
Using activemodel 4.0.4
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.3
Using arel 4.0.2
Using activerecord 4.0.4
Using bundler 1.6.1
Using coffee-script-source 1.7.0
Using execjs 2.0.2
Using coffee-script 2.2.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.0.4
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
Using hike 1.2.3
Using jbuilder 1.5.3
Using jquery-rails 3.1.0

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [generator.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /var/folders/6h/6pjrp51118q0kzwvp_4cmb440000gn/T/bundler20140405-36307-112rp7c/json-1.8.1/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/folders/6h/6pjrp51118q0kzwvp_4cmb440000gn/T/bundler20140405-36307-112rp7c/json-1.8.1/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/json-1.8.1/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: did you try doing `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` as it says at the end?

Comment: Yup I did and another error comes up. Should I post it?

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul

Comment: so it is a xcode 5.1 problem...

Answer (score 1):

This issue, for reference, was resolved on Mavericks by utilizing RVM. Once installation through it was completed, all worked well and error disappeared.