# error occurred while installing crypt (3.1.7)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, bundler, bcrypt

I have an error message while running sudo bundle install:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for ruby/util.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling bcrypt_ext.c
compiling crypt.c
compiling crypt_blowfish.c
compiling crypt_gensalt.c
compiling wrapper.c
linking shared-object bcrypt_ext.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [bcrypt_ext.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/bcrypt-3.1.7/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing bcrypt (3.1.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Then I tried to run sudo gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.7' and have below error message:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing bcrypt:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for ruby/util.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling bcrypt_ext.c
compiling crypt.c
compiling crypt_blowfish.c
compiling crypt_gensalt.c
compiling wrapper.c
linking shared-object bcrypt_ext.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [bcrypt_ext.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/bcrypt-3.1.7/gem_make.out
```

After this, I try to run sudo gem install bcrypt, still not working. Any tips?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply\_definedsuppress'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)

Comment: sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install bcrypt

seems to be working!

Comment: If it works, and fixed your problem, you should post an answer to your own question for others stopping by in future.

Answer (score 5):

I had upgraded Xcode from the Mac App Store, and that caused this particular error for me.

The way to fix it in my case: run Xcode and accept the license terms, etc. Then when I ran `bundle install`, it compiled and installed `bcrypt` just fine.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, just did that and everything is working.