# sqlite3 gem compilation error

Tags: ruby, macos, sqlite, rubygems

I am trying to install the sqlite3 gem on OSX Mavericks and I have run into an error that seems tricky to get around. By googling, I've not managed to find anyone else with the same problem.

Basically, when I run the gem install command this is what happens:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for rb_proc_arity()... yes
checking for rb_integer_pack()... no
checking for sqlite3_initialize()... yes
checking for sqlite3_backup_init()... yes
checking for sqlite3_column_database_name()... no
checking for sqlite3_enable_load_extension()... no
checking for sqlite3_load_extension()... no
checking for sqlite3_open_v2()... yes
checking for sqlite3_prepare_v2()... yes
checking for sqlite3_int64 in sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_uint64 in sqlite3.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling backup.c
compiling database.c
database.c:300:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.
compiling exception.c
compiling sqlite3.c
compiling statement.c
linking shared-object sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [sqlite3_native.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
```

I don't know what clang is, but gem seems to be passing an argument which is perhaps deprecated or something? Anybody with any more knowledge about this stuff got any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply\_definedsuppress'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

New version of XCode in Mavericks apparently ships with a compiler that treats unknown passed parameters as **errors**.

To workaround this issue, set the environment variable to `ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future` in order to downgrade the error to a warning.

So to install sqlite3 gem:

`ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install sqlite3`

Reference: http://bruteforce.gr/bypassing-clang-error-unknown-argument.html