# Error Installing Jekyll on Mac OS Mavericks (10.9.2)

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, osx-mavericks, jekyll

Trying to install stable version of Jekyll on OSX Mavericks.  I have Xcode and the command line tools installed, yet I get this error:

---

```
sudo gem install jekyll
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling porter.c
porter.c:359:27: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
      if (a > 1 || a == 1 && !cvc(z, z->k - 1)) z->k--;
                ~~ ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
porter.c:359:27: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this warning
      if (a > 1 || a == 1 && !cvc(z, z->k - 1)) z->k--;
                          ^
                   (                          )
1 warning generated.
compiling porter_wrap.c
linking shared-object stemmer.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [stemmer.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/fast-stemmer-1.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/fast-stemmer-1.0.2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: You used `sudo gem install`. Are you using rvm? Can you paste the result of `which ruby`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply\_definedsuppress'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem appeared with Xcode 5.1. In order to avoid many problems related to MacOS' ruby version (this one and many others), you **really** should use [RVM](https://rvm.io/).

If you don't already have it, install Homebrew first: (it is not absolutely necessary, but allows us to install ruby and its dependencies without a looong compilation)

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

Then, the following command will install RVM and the last version of Ruby:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

Check everything is OK:

```
ruby --version
```

You can now install Jekyll:

```
gem install jekyll
```

---

Now, if you *really* don't want to use RVM, you can execute:

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install jekyll
```

But I bet further problems would come.

Comment: Great answer! But should this say Xcode 5.1 instead of Xcode 1.5?

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely use RVM. Here are the steps:

1. Uninstall any existing XCode by deleting XCode from Applications folder.
2. Install Homebrew.

   ```
   ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
   ```
3. Follow additional instructions listed in Homebrew install.

   ```
   brew doctor
   ```
4. Install RVM.

   ```
   \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
   ```
5. Follow additional instructions upon RVM installation.

   ```
   source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
   ```
6. Install jekyll.

   ```
   gem install jekyll
   ```
7. Test jekyll.

   ```
   $ jekyll serve

   Configuration file: none

           Source: /private/var/log

      Destination: /private/var/log/_site

     Generating... done.

   Server address: ...

   Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1) xcode-select --install

2) brew install ruby

3) sudo gem install jekyll

4) sudo gem install jekyll-import