# Installation's issue with Jsduck gem

Tags: ruby, macos, clang, jsduck

I'm trying to install on my Mac [JSduck](https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck/)

- OSX Mavericks 10.9.2
- Xcode command line tools present

But finding the following errors

[image]

```
MacBook-Pro-di-monili:~ monilinicolo$ sudo gem install jsduck
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jsduck:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [generator.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
MacBook-Pro-di-monili:~ monilinicolo$ sudo jsduck --builtin-classes --output docs
sudo: jsduck: command not found
```

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck/issues/554

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply\_definedsuppress'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)