# Redmine Dependencies installation issue

Tags: rubygems, bundler, redmine

I want to install redmine, refer to:http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall
and I go to step4.,and execute "bundle install --without development test",got an error,
then execute "sudo gem install json -v '1.8.1'" ,got another error.
and I stuck here ,I don't know how to fix this two error.
This is my command & output below:

```
yayaigo-2:redmine yayaigo$ bundle install --without development test
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.1.1
Using i18n 0.6.9
Using multi_json 1.9.2
Using activesupport 3.2.17
Using builder 3.0.0
Using activemodel 3.2.17
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using journey 1.0.4
Using rack 1.4.5
Using rack-cache 1.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using hike 1.2.3
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.2.2
Using actionpack 3.2.17
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.4
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 3.2.17
Using arel 3.0.3
Using tzinfo 0.3.39
Using activerecord 3.2.17
Using activeresource 3.2.17
Using awesome_nested_set 2.1.6
Using bundler 1.6.2
Using coderay 1.1.0
Using rack-ssl 1.3.4

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [generator.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /var/folders/vc/skvcsqcn33s4snfd9jj5xwfc0000gn/T/bundler20140419-48941-iht3ml/json-1.8.1/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/folders/vc/skvcsqcn33s4snfd9jj5xwfc0000gn/T/bundler20140419-48941-iht3ml/json-1.8.1/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/json-1.8.1/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
yayaigo-2:redmine yayaigo$ gem install json -v '1.8.1'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1/.gitignore
yayaigo-2:redmine yayaigo$ sudo gem install json -v '1.8.1'**
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [generator.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/json-1.8.1/gem_make.out
```

Any know how to fix that?
Thanks.
Regards.

To Holger Just:
I try your solution "ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future bundle",
and got error
Then "sudo gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'" ,got another error
I stuck again.
This is my command and output below:

```
yayaigo-2:redmine yayaigo$ ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future bundle install --without development test
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.1.1
Using i18n 0.6.9
Using multi_json 1.9.2
Using activesupport 3.2.17
Using builder 3.0.0
Using activemodel 3.2.17
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using journey 1.0.4
Using rack 1.4.5
Using rack-cache 1.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using hike 1.2.3
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.2.2
Using actionpack 3.2.17
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.4
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 3.2.17
Using arel 3.0.3
Using tzinfo 0.3.39
Using activerecord 3.2.17
Using activeresource 3.2.17
Using awesome_nested_set 2.1.6
Using bundler 1.6.2
Using coderay 1.1.0
Using rack-ssl 1.3.4


Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system Rubygems.
You can cancel this installation and run:

    bundle install --path vendor/bundle

to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your password
and install the bundled gems to Rubygems using sudo.

Password: 
Sorry, try again.


Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system Rubygems.
You can cancel this installation and run:

    bundle install --path vendor/bundle

to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your password
and install the bundled gems to Rubygems using sudo.

Password: 
Installing json 1.8.1
Installing rdoc 3.12.2
Installing thor 0.19.1
Installing railties 3.2.17
Installing jquery-rails 2.0.3
Installing mysql2 0.3.15
Installing net-ldap 0.3.1
Installing ruby-openid 2.3.0
Installing rack-openid 1.4.2
Installing rails 3.2.17
Installing redcarpet 2.3.0

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for xcrun... yes
checking for Magick-config... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.2. Can't find Magick-config in /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/yayaigo/NVPACK/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Users/yayaigo/NVPACK/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools:/Users/yayaigo/NVPACK/android-sdk-macosx/tools:/Users/yayaigo/NVPACK/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin:/Users/yayaigo/.rvm/bin:/Users/yayaigo/Documents/Projects/quick-cocos2d-x

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/folders/vc/skvcsqcn33s4snfd9jj5xwfc0000gn/T/bundler20140419-50567-1auydlz/rmagick-2.13.2/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/folders/vc/skvcsqcn33s4snfd9jj5xwfc0000gn/T/bundler20140419-50567-1auydlz/rmagick-2.13.2/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/rmagick-2.13.2/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.13.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'` succeeds before bundling.
yayaigo-2:redmine yayaigo$ sudo gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for xcrun... yes
checking for Magick-config... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.2. Can't find Magick-config in /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/yayaigo/NVPACK/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Users/yayaigo/NVPACK/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools:/Users/yayaigo/NVPACK/android-sdk-macosx/tools:/Users/yayaigo/NVPACK/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin:/Users/yayaigo/.rvm/bin:/Users/yayaigo/Documents/Projects/quick-cocos2d-x

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/rmagick-2.13.2/gem_make.out
```

And I refer to:http://www.yongbok.net/blog/cant-install-rmagick-2-13-2-cant-find-magick-config/
then "brew install imagemagick" install ok.
then I run this command,got another error.
"ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future sudo gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'"
This is my output and error below:

```
yayaigo-2:redmine yayaigo$ ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future sudo gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for xcrun... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for snprintf() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for AcquireImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for AffinityImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for AffinityImages() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for AutoGammaImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for AutoLevelImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for BlueShiftImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for ConstituteComponentTerminus() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for DeskewImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for EncipherImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for EqualizeImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for FloodfillPaintImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for FunctionImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for GetAuthenticIndexQueue() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for GetAuthenticPixels() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for GetImageAlphaChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for GetVirtualPixels() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for LevelImageColors() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for LevelColorsImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for LevelizeImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for LiquidRescaleImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for MagickLibAddendum() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for OpaquePaintImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for QueueAuthenticPixels() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for RemapImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for RemoveImageArtifact() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for SelectiveBlurImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for SetImageAlphaChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for SetImageArtifact() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for SetMagickMemoryMethods() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for SparseColorImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for SyncAuthenticPixels() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for TransformImageColorspace() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for TransparentPaintImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for TransparentPaintImageChroma() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for QueryMagickColorname() new signature... yes
checking for Image.type in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for DrawInfo.kerning in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for DrawInfo.interline_spacing in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for DrawInfo.interword_spacing in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for DitherMethod in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for MagickFunction in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for ImageLayerMethod in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for long double in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for AlphaChannelType.CopyAlphaChannel... yes
checking for AlphaChannelType.BackgroundAlphaChannel... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.BlurCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.DistortCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.LinearBurnCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.LinearDodgeCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.MathematicsCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.PegtopLightCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.PinLightCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.VividLightCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompressionType.DXT1Compression... yes
checking for CompressionType.DXT3Compression... yes
checking for CompressionType.DXT5Compression... yes
checking for CompressionType.ZipSCompression... yes
checking for CompressionType.PizCompression... yes
checking for CompressionType.Pxr24Compression... yes
checking for CompressionType.B44Compression... yes
checking for CompressionType.B44ACompression... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.BarrelDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.BarrelInverseDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.BilinearForwardDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.BilinearReverseDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.DePolarDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.PolarDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.PolynomialDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.ShepardsDistortion... yes
checking for DitherMethod.NoDitherMethod... yes
checking for FilterTypes.KaiserFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.WelshFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.ParzenFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.LagrangeFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.BohmanFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.BartlettFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.SentinelFilter... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.PowEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.LogEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.ThresholdEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.ThresholdBlackEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.ThresholdWhiteEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.GaussianNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.ImpulseNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.LaplacianNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.MultiplicativeNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.PoissonNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.UniformNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.CosineEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.SineEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.AddModulusEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickFunction.ArcsinFunction... yes
checking for MagickFunction.ArctanFunction... yes
checking for MagickFunction.PolynomialFunction... yes
checking for MagickFunction.SinusoidFunction... yes
checking for ImageLayerMethod.FlattenLayer... yes
checking for ImageLayerMethod.MergeLayer... yes
checking for ImageLayerMethod.MosaicLayer... yes
checking for ImageLayerMethod.TrimBoundsLayer... yes
checking for VirtualPixelMethod.HorizontalTileVirtualPixelMethod... yes
checking for VirtualPixelMethod.VerticalTileVirtualPixelMethod... yes
checking for VirtualPixelMethod.HorizontalTileEdgeVirtualPixelMethod... yes
checking for VirtualPixelMethod.VerticalTileEdgeVirtualPixelMethod... yes
checking for VirtualPixelMethod.CheckerTileVirtualPixelMethod... yes
checking for ruby/io.h... yes
checking for rb_frame_this_func() in ruby.h,ruby/io.h... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile


======================================================================
Sat 19Apr14 03:22:26
This installation of RMagick 2.13.2 is configured for
Ruby 2.0.0 (universal.x86_64-darwin13) and ImageMagick 6.8.7 Q16 
======================================================================



make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling rmagick.c
compiling rmdraw.c
rmdraw.c:315:15: warning: comparison of constant 100 with expression of type 'WeightType' is always true [-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
        if (w < 100 || w > 900)
            ~ ^ ~~~
rmdraw.c:315:26: warning: comparison of constant 900 with expression of type 'WeightType' is always false [-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
        if (w < 100 || w > 900)
                       ~ ^ ~~~
2 warnings generated.
compiling rmenum.c
rmenum.c:450:13: warning: 4 enumeration values not handled in switch: 'DivideSrcCompositeOp', 'MinusSrcCompositeOp', 'DarkenIntensityCompositeOp'... [-Wswitch]
    switch (op)
            ^
rmenum.c:565:13: warning: enumeration values 'LZMACompression', 'JBIG1Compression', and 'JBIG2Compression' not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
    switch (ct)
            ^
rmenum.c:674:12: warning: 9 enumeration values not handled in switch: 'SincFastFilter', 'LanczosSharpFilter', 'Lanczos2Filter'... [-Wswitch]
    switch(type)
           ^
rmenum.c:922:12: warning: 5 enumeration values not handled in switch: 'Average9InterpolatePixel', 'Average16InterpolatePixel', 'BlendInterpolatePixel'... [-Wswitch]
    switch(interpolate)
           ^
4 warnings generated.
compiling rmfill.c
compiling rmilist.c
rmilist.c:448:12: warning: 'MapImages' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    (void) MapImages(new_images, map, dither);
           ^
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.7-7/include/ImageMagick-6/magick/deprecate.h:203:3: note: 'MapImages' declared here
  MapImages(Image *,const Image *,const MagickBooleanType)
  ^
1 warning generated.
compiling rmimage.c
rmimage.c:8159:12: warning: 'MapImage' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    (void) MapImage(new_image, map, dither);
           ^
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.7-7/include/ImageMagick-6/magick/deprecate.h:201:3: note: 'MapImage' declared here
  MapImage(Image *,const Image *,const MagickBooleanType)
  ^
rmimage.c:10705:17: warning: 'RecolorImage' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    new_image = RecolorImage(image, order, matrix, &exception);
                ^
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.7-7/include/ImageMagick-6/magick/deprecate.h:143:4: note: 'RecolorImage' declared here
  *RecolorImage(const Image *,const size_t,const double *,ExceptionInfo *)
   ^
2 warnings generated.
compiling rminfo.c
compiling rmmain.c
compiling rmmontage.c
compiling rmpixel.c
compiling rmstruct.c
compiling rmutil.c
rmutil.c:1612:43: warning: format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure) [-Wformat-security]
    rb_raise(Class_FatalImageMagickError, GetLocaleExceptionMessage(severity, reason));
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
rmutil.c:1652:20: warning: format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure) [-Wformat-security]
        rb_warning(msg);
                   ^~~
2 warnings generated.
linking shared-object RMagick2.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [RMagick2.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/rmagick-2.13.2/gem_make.out
```

....

And finally I execute "ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future bundle install --without development test"

```
Your bundle is complete!
Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Did I succefully finish the step4? I am not sure,it say "Gems in the groups development and test were not installed." what is the mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply\_definedsuppress'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)

Answer (score 0):

To cite from the relase notes of [Apple's XCode 5.1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/xc5_release_notes/xc5_release_notes.html):

> The Apple LLVM compiler in Xcode 5.1 treats unrecognized command-line
>   options as errors. This issue has been seen when building both Python
>   native extensions and Ruby Gems, where some invalid compiler options
>   are currently specified. Projects using invalid compiler options will
>   need to be changed to remove those options. To help ease that
>   transition, the compiler will temporarily accept an option to
>   downgrade the error to a warning:
>
> ```
> -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future
> ```
>
> **Note:** This option will not be supported in the future.
>
> To workaround
>   this issue, set the ARCHFLAGS environment variable to downgrade the
>   error to a warning. For example, you can install a Python native
>   extension with:
>
> ```
> $ ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future easy_install ExtensionName
> ```
>
> Similarly, you can install a Ruby Gem with:
>
> ```
> $ ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install GemName
> ```

Thus, you can install your Gems by running the following command on your Mac:

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future bundle install --without development test
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command line. It works pretty well to me:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```