# Error installing Rails on mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I do "sudo gem install rails" this is what I get:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [generator.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

Any idea on how to fix?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply\_definedsuppress'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)