# Error installing gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I typed 'gem install middleman' in my terminal and got the following error message:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing middleman:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
compiling hitimes.c
make: gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [hitimes.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/hitimes-1.2.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/hitimes-1.2.2/ext/hitimes/c/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Found a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429145/error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-ruby-extconf-rb-mac-osx

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing `gcc-4.2`

Do you have any GCC installed (if you're on a Mac, you need to install Xcode)?

```
which gcc
```

If you already have a version of gcc, you can simply symlink to it

```
ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

Comment: this was certainly an easy-win for me