# How do I get npm to install/update itself in the selected nvm directory?

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I have installed node via nvm. I am trying to update npm. Current version:

```
npm -v
1.4.28
$ which npm
/Users/per/.nvm/v0.10.33/bin/npm
$ node -v
v0.10.33
```

Installing npm:

```
cd
curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh

/Users/per/.node/bin/npm -> /Users/per/.node/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm@2.1.11 /Users/per/.node/lib/node_modules/npm
It worked
```

Checking npm version after install:

```
npm -v
1.4.28
$ which npm
/Users/per/.nvm/v0.10.33/bin/npm
```

How do I get npm to install itself in the nvm directory?

EDIT =================================

The root cause for wanting to replace npm with a new version is that I get a load of error messages when using it. One of the messages say:

```
imagemin@3.1.0: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0","npm":">=2.1.5"} (current:{"node":"0.10.33","npm":"1.4.28"})
```

So that one seems to explicitly ask for a newer version of npm. The others are mostly about "Unmet dependencies". There are loads of them, but here is one example:

```
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/per/.node/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data requires async@'~0.9.0' but will load
```

Comment: I'm curious, is there a specific reason why you need to update npm?

Comment: I think it's become corrupt. I get a load of error messages when I try to install stuff. 'npm cache clean' does not help, so I'm trying to replace the old version.

Comment: What are the error messages?

Comment: I've updated the question with more info regarding the error messages.

Comment: That doesn't look like npm is corrupt to me. `imagemin`'s npm version requirement is way too high. My guess is that it's explicitly requiring an npm version because it uses a "newer" dependency version symbol (`^` IIRC) which is only supported in "newer" npm versions (although "newer" here is actually quite old by now and it's definitely supported by the npm shipped with node v0.10.33).

Comment: I'm not sure about the `async` module error, the line seems to be missing additional text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what finally worked for me: It seemed like sass and compass had not been installed properly. I started investigating why and stumbled across this solution.

I fairly recently upgraded to OSX Mavericks, which seems to have broken the possibility to install rubygems using native extensions. By running the commands below I first reinstated functional command line tools.

```
$ sudo xcode-select --install
$ xcode-select --print-path
```

Furthermore, I had to install the gem using the following flag:

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install <gemName>
```

After having done this, everything started working as it should. Running npm install  no longer produced a load of error messages, so there was no need to replace the npm used with nvm.

References:

- [Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul/22355874#22355874)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23525839/1158376

Answer (score 0):

In Win 7
Try this:
- install node.js from website. (0.10.33 version) (in my case destination folder was **C:\Program Files\nodejs**)

- npm was installed automatically (i guess),  npm verstion -  1.4.28, and plased in
  **C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm**
- after installing(updating) new npm (npm install npm -g), destination folder was 
  **C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm**

Copy all from folder2 to folder1.
and check verstion;

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As it turned out, there was no need to replace npm, so I guess I was asking for the wrong thing.