# Unable to install Jekyll with gem install

Tags: rubygems, jekyll

I am trying to install Jekyll on my Mac with the command:

```
sudo gem install jekyll
```

However I get the error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Check this! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429145/error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-ruby-extconf-rb-mac-osx

Answer (score 0):

The key info there is:

```
You have to install development tools first.
```

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/9353468/500526