# osx rails intall error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to install rails on a clean os x mavericks machine. For some reason it is not working

```
$ sudo gem install rails
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.bundle
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [generator.bundle] Error 1
```

Here are some more details:

```
$ rvm -v
rvm 1.25.28 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.6.3
```

Are there more things I have to install? I don't really understand the error

Comment: What version of xcode do you have?

Comment: xcode-select version 2333

Answer (score 0):

I found this little piece of magic and it installed fine:

`curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Paulche/9713531/raw/1e57fbb440d36ca5607d1739cc6151f373b234b6/gistfile1.txt | sudo patch /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/rbconfig.rb`

thanks to this post: [Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)