# An error occurred while installing byebug (7.0.0), and bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby, rubygems, byebug

When I run bundle install, I get this error: 
[image: rubygems bundle install byebug error.]

In case the picture doesn't load, here is the error message:
"An error occured while installing byebug (7.0.0), and bundler cannot continue."

I found a few answers that suggested making changes to the Gemfile, which I did and that did not work.  After those unsuccessful attempts, I uninstalled rails and reinstalled it.

I am working on a macbook pro, osx yosemite version 10.10.5.

Comment: FWIW: you will get better feedback if you post the error message as text as opposed to as a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks... What part of the error message would you have put in text?  Under the screenshot I included everything in red. @orde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of XCODE are you using and do you have the command line tools extensions for it installed? Also, byebug is noted elsewhere has previously having compiler options that are unsupported by the xcode compilers.  With xcode-5.1 you can turn these errors into warnings.  Later versions may or may not permit this.  See: [Ruby Gem install Json fails on Mavericks and Xcode 5.1 - unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352838/ruby-gem-install-json-fails-on-mavericks-and-xcode-5-1-unknown-argument-mul)

Comment: The version of xcode is 7.1.  I don't have command line tools and i'm not using xcode for anything.  Do I need to be?

Comment: Thanks.  The accepted answer on the referred question fixed perfectly.